# To install Xcode in Windows XP

Tags: windows, xcode4.3

I would like to know if I can install Xcode with Windows XP.If possible please provide the document link also.Thank you very much for any help in advance...

Comment: XCode is the developer environment exclusively for mac OS .So you have to look forward for some workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly possible.

There are two routes;

Install OSx86 (aka iATKOS / Kalyway) on a second partition/disk and dual boot.
Run Mac OS X Server under VMWare.
The first route requires modifying (or using a pre-modified) image of Leopard that can be installed on a regular PC. This is not as hard as you would think, although your success/effort ratio will depend upon how closely the hardware in your PC matches that in Mac hardware - e.g. if you're running a Core 2 Duo on an Intel Motherboard, with a NVidia graphics card you are laughing. If you're running an AMD machine or something without SSE3 it gets a little more involved.

If you purchase (or already own) a version of Leopard then this is a gray area since the Leopard EULA states you may only run it on an "Apple Labeled" machine. As many point out if you stick an Apple sticker on your PC you're probably covered.

The second option is the more costly. The EULA for the workstation version of Leopard prevents it from being run under emulation and as a result there's no support in VMWare for this. Leopard server however CAN be run under emulation and can be used for desktop purposes. Leopard server and VMWare are expensive however.

If you're interested in option 1) I would suggest starting at Insanelymac and reading the OSx86 sections.

I do think you should consider whether the time you will invest is going to be worth the money you will save though. It was for me because I enjoy tinkering with this type of stuff and I started during the early iPhone betas, months before their App Store became available.

Alternatively you could pickup a low-spec Mac Mini from eBay. You don't need much horse power to run the SDK and you can always sell it on later if you decide to stop development or buy a better Mac.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not install XCode on a Windows machine. You need MacOS to run XCode.
Although you can install VMWare Server on your windows machine and then install MacOS on that virtual server and can install the XCode on that MacOS server.

But to install MacOS(VMWare server) and start working on it. your hardware must support virtualization.

To install VMWare following links might be useful.

1. http://www.petri.co.il/virtual_install_vmware_server.htm
2. http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Installing_VMware_Server_2.0_on_Windows_Systems
3. Or there is always [Google](http://www.google.co.in/search?rls=en&q=install%20vmware%20server%20on%20windows%20xp&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

YOu can check if your CPU supports virtualization [here](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-030729.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Since Xcode is an software of Mac OS so its not possible to run Xcode without Mac OS. And for Mac OS you can dual boot your computer with a Mac OS or simply you can just use VMWare to install Mac OS in your laptop or PC. Just the necessary requirement for installing Mac OS through Dual boot or through VMWare is that you need really high configuration in your laptop or PC, Like atleast you require 5th Generation core processor with atleast 4 cores also you require more than 4GB RAM for better functioning of Mac OS. Mac OS can be installed with 2nd generation processors, Dual core, and 2 GB RAM but it will take too much time. Which is not worth installing Mac OS in your laptop or PC. And even after installing you won't be able to use Xcode efficiently with such a low configuration. So it is recommended to have 5th Generation processor with 4 core and atleast 4GB RAM.

If you have this configuration than you need some files and software to install Mac OS in your Laptop.

For installation through VMWare you can prefer to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wodqGvug6e0

And I have the required file for the same as in video but not uploaded to the internet.